# Identify file extensions using endswith: not supported for file objects?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, argparse, ends-with

The program I am running needs to identify if an imported file is a gzipped.  The files are coming in using argparse:

```
parser.add_argument('file_sources', nargs='*', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin, help='Accepts one or more fasta files, no arguments defaults to stdin')
options = parser.parse_args()
open_files = options.file_sources
```

and stored in a list where the program loops through the list and determines whether that file is gzipped based on the file ext `.gz`:

```
open_files = options.file_sources
#if there is nothing in the list, then read from stdin
if not open_files:
    open_files = [sys.stdin]
#if there are files present in argparse then read their extentions
else:
    opened_files = []
    for _file in open_files:
        if _file.endswith(".gz"):
            _fh = gzip.open(_file,'r')
            opened_files.append(_fh)
        else:
            _fh = open(_file,'r')
            opened_files.append(_fh)
```

The code breaks at `_file.endswith(".gz"):`, giving the error `'file' has no attribute 'endswith`.  If I delete the argparse type, _file goes from being a file object to a string.  Doing this causes `endwith()` to work, but now the file is just a string bearing its name.

How can I keep the functionality of the file while also interpreting its file extension (and not having to use absolute paths as in `os.path.splitext` since I'm just taking files from the program's current directory)?

Comment: Why are you reopening files that are already open?  The `argparse.FileType` opens the files when it reads the strings.  If you want to open them yourself, just accept strings.  Then you can apply the `.endswith` test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file` has no attribute `endswith`, but `string` has, so:

change:

```
if _file.endswith(".gz"):
```

to:

```
if _file.name.endswith(".gz"):
```

and as _file is a *file* type, use `open` like this:

```
_fh = gzip.open(_file.name,'r')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @Anzel.  Unfortunately, when I try your recommendation I get:
`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found` coming from line 94 of the `gzip.py` module.  What does it mean to coerce the unicode and how can I get around this to convert filename to a string?

Comment: @ThomasMatthew, please see my updates, it's about your code around `open`

Comment: that must have worked, because I am on to new and better errors.  Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasMatthew, not a problem, glad it helps :)